# Java/Tomcat and Oracle 10g connection

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, odbc, database-connection

I'm new to java and Oracle connection I can't establish a connection from java/tomcat service to Oracle database.

I'm using Java JDK 1.7 and Oracle Version:

```
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product 
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production 
CORE 10.2.0.1.0 Production 
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production 
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

I added a CLASSPATH to the Environment Variables (Windows Server 2003)
`C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\*`

I also added the JAVA bin to PATH and JAVA_HOME (used by TOMCAT)

In this folder there are only two files: `ojdbc14.jar` and `ojdbc14_g.jar`

My java Code:

```
       import java.sql.*;
       ....
       ....

                        try
                        {                              
                                System.out.println("0");
                                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                                System.out.println("1");
                                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/xe",
                                  "username", "password");
                                System.out.println("2");                       
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                                //e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("exc");
                        }
```

Output: (It seems that he throw an exception on `Class.forName`

```
0
exc
```

Comment: And what exception might that be? I suspect a `ClassNotFoundException`, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat, and all Java EE app servers, completely ignore your CLASSPATH environment variable.  Same for IDEs.  I don't have one on any machine that I use.

You should not be altering any scripts to do this, either.

Every Java EE app server has a hierarchy of class loaders.

The first to run is the bootstrap class loader.

Next is the server class loader.  The right place for those JARs is the Tomcat server /lib directory.  The /lib directory contains all the JARs that are common to all deployments.  They're loaded before the WAR files on startup.

There's a class loader for each WAR file deployed.  After the server class loader runs, Tomcat treats all the JARs that you put in the WEB-INF/lib and all the .class files you put under WEB-INF/classes as your project CLASSPATH.

Once you've gotten that to work, the next thing is to learn about how to use JNDI lookups.  The code you posted isn't a good idea.  Let Tomcat manage a connection pool for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the classpath as follows:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar
```

the classpath needs to know the jar to use, this is the production driver and the one with the _g is for debugging purpose. Using a wildcard does not work for setting the java classpath. To avoid the need of configuring the classpath you can just copy the ojdbc14.jar to the `$tomcat.home/lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just print Out `e.printStackTrace();` and see weather exception occur...
if it in`Class.forName()`  then that means class path is not set properly...
every thing seam  fine..  just check..in class path

Answer (score 0):

Driver name is worng.

It must be oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver instead of what you are using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the ojdbc14.jar file in your Deployment Assembly in your project. Using eclipse :

> proj --> properties --> Deployment Assembly --> select /webContent --> Add --> JavaBuildPathEnteries --> Next --> ojdbc**.jar --> finish.